# Normalize a json column that has has column names passed as value in python

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, flatten, json-normalize

Edit: sample json of details column:

```html
{6591: '[]',
 8112: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659453223851}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659454209024, 'location': [-73.7895605, 40.6869539]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659453289013, 'location': [-73.8124575, 40.7091602]}]",
 5674: '[]',
 4236: '[]',
 3148: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659121571280}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659122768105, 'location': [-74.220351348, 40.748419051]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659121605076, 'location': [-74.189452444, 40.715865856]}]",
 3408: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659113772531}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659114170204, 'location': [-73.9469142, 40.671488]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659113832693, 'location': [-73.956379, 40.6669802]}]",
 1438: '[]',
 3634: '[]',
 5060: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659190337964}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659190367182, 'location': [-76.614058283, 39.292697049]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659190345722, 'location': [-76.614058283, 39.292697049]}]",
 6614: '[]',
 7313: '[]',
 7653: '[]',
 9446: '[]',
 1237: '[]',
 6974: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659383554887}, {'name': 'adminCompletion', 'time': 1659386192031, 'data': {'adminId': 'ZFQCAL6aeS', 'sendNotificationFromAdminComplete': False}}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659385764198, 'location': [-73.943001009, 40.705886527]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659383653199, 'location': [-73.94038015, 40.814893186]}]",
 762: '[]',
 4843: '[]',
 8682: '[]',
 7271: '[]',
 4672: "[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659131562088}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659131937387, 'location': [-87.62621, 41.9015626]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659131637316, 'location': [-87.6263294, 41.9094856]}]"}
```

I have a dataframe columns like 'details' and 'id'. It looks like this. I want to completely flatten details column.

```html
details id
[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659479418}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659452651073, 'location': [-75.040536278, 40.034055]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659451650, 'location': [-75.1609003, 39.947729034]}] 1
[]  2
[]  3
[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659126581459}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659128206850, 'location': [-80.3165751, 25.8625698]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659126641679, 'location': [-80.2511886, 25.921769]}]   4
[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659120813100}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659121980125, 'location': [-76.642292, 39.307895253]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659120903093, 'location': [-76.741190426, 39.34240617]}]  5
[]  6
[]  7
[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659217203753}, {'name': 'adminCompletion', 'time': 1659217336224, 'data': {'adminId': '~R~WZt7bKO979BRTqHyarS2p', 'sendNotification': False}}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659217308939, 'location': [-73.941830752, 40.702405857]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659217288936, 'location': [-73.941830752, 40.702405857]}]  8
[{'name': 'start', 'time': 1659189824814}, {'name': 'arrival', 'time': 1659191937100, 'location': [-76.406627, 39.984]}, {'name': 'departure', 'time': 1659189915191, 'location': [-76.614515552, 39.292407218]}]   9
[]  10
```

what is expected from this is:

```html
start_time  admincompletiontime adminId sendnotification    arrival_time    arrival_location    departure_time  departure_location  id
1659479418              1.65945E+12 [-75.040536278, 40.034055]  1659451650  [-75.1609003, 39.947729034] 1
                                2
                                3
1.65913E+12             1.65913E+12 [-80.3165751, 25.8625698]   1.65913E+12 [-80.2511886, 25.921769]    4
1.65922E+12 1.65922E+12 ~R~WZt7bKO979BRTqHyarS2p    FALSE   1.65922E+12 [-73.941830752, 40.702405857]   1.65922E+12  [-73.941830752, 40.702405857]  8
```

I want to extract all the columns that are passed as values. pd.json_normalize() did not work for me in this case. please suggest.

Comment: can you please share the dataframe in dict format (`df.loc[:20].to_dict()`). it will be easy for people to load

Comment: the first snippet which you shared it list of jsons or a dataframe ?

Comment: On a side note: The first arrival time is UNIX seconds while all others are UNIX milliseconds.

Comment: It is a dataframe. it has other column as Id. and I have just changed the numbers to random timestamps. please ignore the format of those timestamps.

Comment: Ok.. since it is a dataframe , please post the output of `df.loc[:20].to_dict()`

Comment: @srinath I have updated the question with dict sample

Comment: So your sample data is just a dictionary of strings, not actually objects?

Comment: Yes, I think so. .

Answer (score 0):

Your data is pretty scuffed, you need to clean it up, but following a pattern like this should start you in the right direction:

```
from ast import literal_eval

data = {key:literal_eval(value) for key, value in data.items()}
data = [[{y['name']:{'time':y['time'],'location':y.get('location')}} for y in x] for x in data.values() if x]
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(x) for x in data])
df = (df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
        .bfill()
        .dropna()
        .drop_duplicates('start.time')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     start.time  arrival.time               arrival.location  departure.time             departure.location  adminCompletion.time
0  1.659453e+12  1.659454e+12      [-73.7895605, 40.6869539]    1.659453e+12      [-73.8124575, 40.7091602]          1.659386e+12
1  1.659122e+12  1.659454e+12      [-73.7895605, 40.6869539]    1.659453e+12      [-73.8124575, 40.7091602]          1.659386e+12
2  1.659114e+12  1.659123e+12  [-74.220351348, 40.748419051]    1.659122e+12  [-74.189452444, 40.715865856]          1.659386e+12
3  1.659190e+12  1.659114e+12       [-73.9469142, 40.671488]    1.659114e+12       [-73.956379, 40.6669802]          1.659386e+12
4  1.659384e+12  1.659190e+12  [-76.614058283, 39.292697049]    1.659190e+12  [-76.614058283, 39.292697049]          1.659386e+12
5  1.659132e+12  1.659386e+12  [-73.943001009, 40.705886527]    1.659384e+12   [-73.94038015, 40.814893186]          1.659386e+12
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for bfill().. also, I am trying to use data = {key:literal_eval(value) for key, value in df.items()}
data = [[{y['name']:{'time':y['time'],'location':y.get('location')}, 'data':y.get('data')} for y in x] for x in data.values() if x]
df_final = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(x) for x in data])  But it is not handling null values, but it is giving me all the columns